# Ruby / Mongoid - How to increment a value in a collection and return the new value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm updating some Ruby on Rails code that uses a pretty outdated version of Mongoid.  I have the following line of code which gets the first document in a collection and increments the field `nextid` by 1, then returns the new value:

`surveyid = SurveyId.first.safely.inc(:nextid, 1)`

I've updated Mongoid to version 6.0.3, which no longet has a `safely` method.  If I just use:

`surveyid = SurveyId.first.inc(:nextid, 1)`

It works, but `inc` doesn't return anything and I have no idea what the new value is.

What's the equivalent code in newer Mongoid versions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of Mongoid (7+):

```
 surveyid = SurveyId.first.inc(nextid: 1).nextid
```

`inc` returns the updated object when the operation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I got this figured out.  I found a gem that does exactly what I want called [mongoid_auto_increment](https://github.com/proton/mongoid_auto_increment).

Now I can just add an auto-incrementing field to my collection and be done with it.  Also, the [source code](https://github.com/proton/mongoid_auto_increment/blob/master/lib/mongoid_auto_increment/incrementor.rb) for this Gem illustrates how to increment a value and get the new value, though I didn't really dig into it too much since I just decided to use the gem instead:

```
  def inc
    if defined?(::Mongoid::VERSION) && ::Mongoid::VERSION >= '5'
      collection.find(query).find_one_and_update({ '$inc' => { number: @step } }, new: true, upsert: true, return_document: :after)['number']
    elsif defined?(::Mongoid::VERSION) && ::Mongoid::VERSION >= '3'
      collection.find(query).modify({ '$inc' => { number: @step } }, new: true, upsert: true)['number']
    else
      opts = {
        "query"  => query,
        "update" => {"$inc" => { "number" => @step }},
        "new"    => true # return the modified document
      }
      collection.find_and_modify(opts)["number"]
    end
   end
```